# Display number of running Azure VM's on a dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard, azure-resource-graph

I'd like to create a dashboard in the Azure Portal that displays the number of active virtual machines per resource group. In this case I'm not interested in any deallocated or stopped VM's.

Since filtering the virtual machines blade doesn't work for the VM's power state, I turned to the Resource Graph. From there the solution gets close, but it doesn't seem possible to filter on power state (yet).

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| summarize count() by resourceGroup
| order by resourceGroup asc
```

Is there a way to combine this data with another data table to be able to filter on power state and get only the running virtual machines? Or maybe a different solution altogether to just display the number of running VM's on a dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope the example below works for you

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| where properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus=="VM running"
| summarize count() by resourceGroup
| order by resourceGroup asc
```

Cheers,

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the suggestion! Since this provides the answer to the actual question, I'll mark this as the answer. The other suggestion by @Guru Pasupathy is a good one too, but will not provide the answer to my use case.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a table that holds the PowerState of the VM in the Resource Graph schema (at least I couldn't find it)

Since you had stated that you would also like to hear about altogether a different approach, I want to suggest the PowerShell route

You can get the PowerState of the VM using the below command

```
Get-AzVM -Status
```

[image]

This output you may write to a Azure table storage. (this link has details of how to use PowerShell to interact with Azure Storage Accounts [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell]

You can build a Power BI report on top of this table storage filtering only for **PowerState == running** and light up your report.

Now to schedule this, you will need to

a) Create an Automation Account. Details on how to create automation account can be found here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account]

b) Create a PowerShell runbook which get the VM status and inserts rows to table storage

c) Create a schedule and link the runbook to it. 
Details on how to schedule can be found here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules]

Thus, using Azure Automation Account and a Runbook (point b) you can setup a schedule and link the runbook with that schedule. Whenever the runbook executes it gets the current powerstatus and uploads it to Azure Table storage as per the schedule which would keep the PowerBI updated.

Hope this helps