# In Azure, how to get the VM historical count

Tags: azure, graph, virtual-machine

I am looking for creating the graph of actual VM in the Azure subscription. Ability to show the active VM trend in some graph format.

Either grafana or Resource Graph system.

Answer (score 0):

> Ability to show the active VM trend in some graph format.

*Here is the code to show active VM in the azure dashboard*

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| where properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus=="VM running"
| summarize count() by resourceGroup
| order by resourceGroup asc
```

*for more information you can check with this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63948028) thread.*